# related products (related.phtml) collection showing all products in one custom theme and just one of products showing in the other theme

Tags: magento-enterprise, theme, default

it is so weird and I used the template path hints and everything is reading from the default theme but one of the themes is working properly and one other is not

```
$this->getItemCollection()
```

in related.phtml has 1 product for one of the themes and has more than 8 products in the other theme I tried to remove the themes or rename theme but I found that the problem is not from

```
app/design/frontend/enterprise/mytheme
```

problem is somewhere else I also checked the
app/code/core/Enterprise/TargetRule/Block/Product/abstract.php 
I cannot find why it happens

update:we found that when added to cart it will be removed from results of related now how to solve this default filter of magento?

https://gist.github.com/arosenhagen/2489863

this worked for me although I changed my Targetrule folder not the one mentioned and now i can see the products even if they are in the cart
but still i don't have all my products in related

any idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> I have also face this problem a long time ago, I refine this problem
>   by getting the product list based on storeID, Make the different store
>   view and get the correct data listing everywhere. Some where have
>   magento EAV Attribute model show this error get the product listing
>   anyhow, Please go to store view solution may be this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to this one: [Target rule upsells](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/1143/146) that I posted a long time ago.  For me it was for upsells but it's the same logic for related.
It's because when saving a rule, all the relations are removed and recreated.
When retrieving the collection of related products this collection is cached (store view related) in a table to be retrieved from there.
But if the indexer is set to 'real_time' (Update on save) the rule gets applied when saving a product but only for that product.
So in one store view your get the cached results, and in an other one you get the results for a single product.

@Carco implemented a fix for this that [can be found here](https://github.com/magendooro/targetrulefix).
Give that a try. maybe it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you, my version is 1.14 and unfortunately it didn't help and I went to the Caro answer step by step and in all of it I didn;t need to change it,it was already right and also I tried switching to manual no effect

Comment: I copy pasted his folders too, no effect unfortunately, but the index problem seems right to me too